# Huge binary number Conversion

Tags: matlab, math, vector, decimal

I have the following question,

working on *Matlab* I have a very large vector containing lets say ones and zeros, and I want to convert it into decimal, the thing is that the number is way to big so a variable can not hold it, so I thought braking it into small pieces that are within the acceptable boundaries and converting those pieces into decimal numbers that will be stored in a matrix or vector. I was wondering if you have any suggestions on how to implement that or a better way all together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with "the number is way to big so a variable can not hold it"? My matlab supports numbers up to 1e300. I mean is your vector just ONE number? how long is it? What about `reshape` and `bi2de`?

Comment: Well as you know there is a limit to how big a number can be for lets say a variable of type integer to hold it. The vector that i use is bigger than that when converted to decimal.

Comment: Do you just want to break the big number down or do you expect that the decimal array correctly represents the decimal digits of the number? In the latter case, one should use some BigInteger package.

Comment: You will understand better what i want to do if you read my comment on Divakar's answer. Basically there is a huge vector of data, not only ones and zeros (but they work fine for illustration purposes) but also numbers between -0 ... 127 for lets say base128 numbers, and I need to translate this into a decimal number, or at least a unique identifier (eg the array with the braked down values as Divakar suggests) that i can later on use to get back my original vector.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, this is not what the accepted answer does. What actually happens is that the string is broken down and interpreted as array of numerical values. By their nature, these are binary numbers. Only while printing them out are the binaries translated into decimals. Please also regard that you can not, in general, change the basis of the number representation this way. -- But if it works for you in this present form, then use it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but unfortunately that's the best way I could think of, because of the memory limitations. An int64 for example can only hold intmax('int64') as a maximum value. So by breaking down that vector of numbers I can translate it successfully into a decimal.

Comment: or at least an array of decimals in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Given binary number
comp = '1010101011010110010010101001';
decnum_tobe_stored = bin2dec(comp) %%// To be used for verification

%%// Parameters
ndigits = 4; %%// Number of binary digits used per element for storage.

%%// Storing Process
app1 = ndigits - rem(numel(comp),ndigits);
comp = [repmat('0',[1 app1]) comp];

bin_array = reshape(comp,ndigits,[])' %%//' This is your binary storage medium
dec_array = bin2dec(bin_array) %%// This is your decimal storage medium

%%// Retrieving Process
pf = fliplr(ndigits.*(0:size(bin_array,1)-1));
v2 = power(2,pf)';%//'
ret_number = sum(dec_array.*v2); %%// Retrieved number

%%// Verfication
check_error = isequal(ret_number,decnum_tobe_stored) %%// org_number must be same as verify_decnum for this technique
```

**Output**

```
decnum_tobe_stored =
   179135657

bin_array =
0000
1010
1010
1101
0110
0100
1010
1001

dec_array =
     0
    10
    10
    13
     6
     4
    10
     9

check_error =
     1
```

**Bigger case**

Let's suppose you have a binary number as this -

```
comp = '10101010110101100100101010011010101101010101010101101011001111'
```

You would know that you are limited by `bin2dec`'s capability of allowing a maximum number of binary digits as `52`, so you can use `ndigits = 52`. After running the code, your decimal storage array would have this partitioned data -

```
dec_array =
          683
   1.5686e+15
```

You can easily visualize the entire data if you have `format longe` enabled. Thus,

```
dec_array =

     6.830000000000000e+02
     1.568619453831887e+15
```

**Greedy storage case:** This is applicable if you really want to squeeze in a lot of data into a very small storage array.

**Code**

```
%%// Given binary number
comp = ['10101010110101100100101010011010101101010101010101101011001001' ...
    '01010011010101011010101010101101011001001010100110101010110101' ...
    '01010110110101011010110010010101001101010101101010101010110101' ...
    '10010010101001101010101101010100110010010101001101010101101010' ...
    '10101011010110010010101001101010101101010101100100101010011010' ...
    '10101101010101010110101100100101010011010101011010101010101010' ...
    '11010101010101101011001001010100110101010110101010101010110101' ...
    '10010010101001101010101101010101010110101100100101010011010101' ...
    '01101010101010101101011001001010100110101010110101010101011010' ...
    '11001001010100110101010110101010101011010110010010101001101010' ...
    '10110101010101011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100' ...
    '11010101011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101' ...
    '01011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101010110' ...
    '10110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101010110101100' ...
    '10010101001101010101101011001001010100110101010110101100100101' ...
    '01001101010101101011001001010100110101010110101100100101010011' ...
    '11010101010101101011001001010100110101010110101010101010110101' ...
    '10010010101001101010101101010101010110101100100101010011010101' ...
    '01101010101010101101011001001010100110101010110101010101011010' ...
    '11001001010100110101010110101010101011010110010010101001101010' ...
    '10110101010101011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100' ...
    '11010101011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101' ...
    '01011010110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101010110' ...
    '10110010010101001101010101101011001001010100110101010110101100' ...
    '0101010110101100100101010011010101011010110010010101001'];

%%// Parameters
ndigits = 52; %%// Number of digits allowed

%%// Storing Process
app1 = ndigits - rem(numel(comp),ndigits);
comp = [repmat('0',[1 app1]) comp];

bin_array = reshape(comp,ndigits,[])'; %%//' This is your binary storage medium
dec_array = bin2dec(bin_array) %%// This is your decimal storage medium

%%// ******** Greedy storage approach ******************
%%// Maximum number of elements that can be packed together
num_ele_cumsum = find(isinf(cumsum(power(1E16,1:24))),1)-1;

dec_array = [zeros(num_ele_cumsum - rem(numel(dec_array),num_ele_cumsum),1) ;dec_array];
dec_array_mat = reshape(dec_array,num_ele_cumsum,[]);
exp_nums = repmat(power(1E16,num_ele_cumsum-1:-1:0)',[1 size(dec_array_mat,2)]);%%//'
cumsum_vals = cumsum(dec_array_mat.*exp_nums,1);
dec_array_compact = cumsum_vals(end,:)'
```

**Output**

```
dec_array =
   2.2929e+10
   3.0024e+15
   1.5971e+15
   .......
   2.7211e+15
   3.0504e+15 (38 rows)

dec_array_compact =
  2.2929e+170
  1.5686e+303
```

Also, note that the retrieving process (not listed here) would be as complicated as the encoding process. So, this would make sense in an extremely memory-limited case I would think.

Comment: well actually I am not using bin2dec because the vector could represent a base7, or base128 etc so I created a simple function to transform that vector into a number, only to realize that i quickly exceed the memory limitations.

Comment: @green_leaf You must realize that in an extremely huge case, storing a vector as a  single number might not be possible.

Comment: Of curse, that is why I am breaking it up into smaller pieces trying to follow your method. That way I should be able to lets say create an array that will represent a huge vector (each row will be the decimal representation of a small enough part of my original vector.)

Comment: Can I get an estimate on how "huge" can this special vector be?

Comment: Hmmm, even I don't now exactly but lets say that one of the smallest values could be a vector of 1000 and above elements. It would be easy if it was a binary representation of a number the thing is though that it could be a eg base70 number that can translate in a very huge decimal number. Until now your solution is working quite good I think. I just made a few changes because as I said I can't use bin2dec, and now what i have ended up with is a  matrix with 'ndigits' rows that I will transform from its respective base into a decimal number.

Comment: @green_leaf Just curious how would you actually represent a number with base more than 10, say a number in base70, if not in binary format?

Comment: @green_leaf You said you have obtained *matrix with 'ndigits' rows*, so is that a matrix of binary numbers or decimal numbers or something else?

Comment: That's okay for numbers less than 10, but for numbers more than 10, you would be needed to invent `symbols` I think.

Comment: Well for example a _base7_ number would be a vector of numbers in the range `[0 1 2 ... 6]`.
Just as a binary number (_base2_) is represented using two symbols `[0 1]`.
So there is nothing stopping me from using a higher base where the symbols are the decimal numbers from _0_ to _base-1_. That final array would just be a list of numbers represented in _baseX_ format.  It could be binary or not, that should be of no importance since we can convert from and to decimal from any base.

Comment: Ok you have accepted this answer, but were you able to make it work for you case?

Comment: I accepted the answer because of no alternatives, and because it was generally going to the right direction, hoping that if in the future someone encounters a similar problem may be able to get some help by reading this thread. 
Yes it did work as given, I only changed it a bit to be able to handle number representations in various bases not only base2 and ended up with an array of decimals just as in your example. 
So **YES** in a few words this answer should help someone go in the right direction.